# Mocking just part of getters when importing the global store

Tags: vuejs2, vuex, vue-test-utils

Any idea if it is possible to mock just a getter from the global store ?

I tried this code but It does not work:

```
import store from '@/store';
import Vuex from "vuex";

const localVue = createLocalVue();
localVue.use(VueRouter);
localVue.use(Vuex);

const wrapper = mount(App, {
      mocks: {
        $store: {
          getters: {
            isLoggedIn: () => true // This is always returning false. I need this getter to return true value
          },
        }
      },
      store, // this is the global store for my application
      localVue,
      router,
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be much easier just to use `mocks` property while mounting the component without calling `localVue.use(Vuex)` and without creating `store` instance:

```
const wrapper = mount(App, {     
  localVue,
  router,
  mocks: {
    $store: {
      getters: {
        isLoggedIn: () => () => true,
      }
    } 
  }
});
```

Comment: Yes, this is much better. I am still new in vuejs :)

Comment: Glad the code helped! :) Btw, there is a very nice book on testing Vue apps - Testing Vue.js Applications by Edd Yerburgh

Answer (score 1):

I solved my problem with inspiration from the Vue Testing Handbook examples [here](https://github.com/lmiller1990/vue-testing-handbook/blob/0d628dbeff073372002b0ffc5d30eb8e46cb5923/demo-app/tests/unit/ComponentWithVuex.spec.js#L9).

```
import * as otherNameThanStore  from '@/store'; // we need to change the name to anyone other than store
import Vuex from "vuex";

const localVue = createLocalVue();
localVue.use(VueRouter);
localVue.use(Vuex);

const store = new Vuex.Store( // attribute name must be store, otherwise typescript will throw this error: is not assignable to parameter of type 'FunctionalComponentMountOptions<Vue>'
  {
  state: {
    ...otherNameThanStore.default.state
  },
  getters: {
    ...otherNameThanStore.default.getters,
    isLoggedIn: (state) => () => true,
  },
}
)

const wrapper = mount(App, {     
      store,
      localVue,
      router,
    });
```

Hope it helps other people :)